# WAMP - Need to know version of compilation VC6 or VC9

Tags: wamp

Can someone pls help me how to find the Compiler version used to compile WAMP Modules (Apache,PHP - VC6 or VC9) ?  I am stuck to install correct PDO Drivers for SQLSERVER.

Answer (score 6):

Use follow

echo phpinfo();

and find "Complier" will show the right compiler version

Comment: This shows the compiler which compiles PHP. But what about the compiler that compiles Apache?

Answer (score 1):

This may help.

As far as I am aware microsoft only provide 32bit versions of the php sqlserver interface dll's.

So it would be simpler to just install a 32bit version of WAMPServer and things will start to work. The 32bit WAMPServer runs just fine on a 64bit Windows, and you will find it much easier to find those more esoteric php_*.dll's that run on 32bit than you will on 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

I fought with this for a little while.
This page was helpful...

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

The "System Requirements" section speaks about version compatibility.

I found that Wampserver 2.4 and SQLSERV30 were both on VC9.